# How to clear cache with specific key in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I created a cache with a key `USERS`:

```
return Cache::remember('USERS', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30), function() {
    return User::orderBy('name')->get();
});
```

I want to clear the `USERS` cache when adding new `User`.
How to clear the `USERS` cache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `Cache::forget()` like this

```php
Cache::forget('USERS');
```

for more info check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache)

Answer (score 2):

To clear the Laravel cache, simply use the forget() function as shown below:

```
Cache::forget('key');
```

You can also retrieve a cache value and can delete it immediately. Technically, you can call it one-time caching.

```
$articles = Cache::pull('key');
```